# Dict/List max by key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following dict:

```
[{'country': 'Armenia', 'population': '3026048'}, {'country': 'Angola', 'population': '25830958'}, {'country': 'Algeria', 'population': '40375954'}, {'country': 'Andorra', 'population': '69165'}, {'country': 'Anguilla', 'population': '14763'}, {'country': 'American Samoa', 'population': '55602'}, {'country': 'Aruba', 'population': '104263'}, {'country': 'Argentina', 'population': '43847277'}, {'country': 'Afghanistan', 'population': '33369945'}, {'country': 'Azerbaijan', 'population': '9868447'}, {'country': 'Australia', 'population': '24309330'}, {'country': 'Antigua and Barbuda', 'population': '92738'}, {'country': 'Albania', 'population': '2903700'}, {'country': 'Austria', 'population': '8569633'}]
```

and the following list

```
[['Andorra', '69165'], ['Afghanistan', '33369945'], ['Algeria', '40375954'], ['American Samoa', '55602'], ['Aruba', '104263'], ['Armenia', '3026048'], ['Angola', '25830958'], ['Azerbaijan', '9868447'], ['Antigua and Barbuda', '92738'], ['Australia', '24309330'], ['Albania', '2903700'], ['Argentina', '43847277'], ['Anguilla', '14763'], ['Austria', '8569633']]
```

How can I extract the country name of the most populated country (the second value in each sublist)

You can provide solution for list or for dict.

Comment: `import operator`, and `max(my_dict, key=operator.itemgetter('population'))`. Note that your "dict" is actually a list of dictionaries, and your "list" is a list of lists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `max` with a key, for the list, it would be:

```
max(lst, key = lambda x: int(x[1]))
# ['Argentina', '43847277']
```

---

Same idea for the dict, with a slightly different key function:

```
max(d, key = lambda x: int(x['population']))
# {'country': 'Argentina', 'population': '43847277'}
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this (for the list of lists):

```
pops = []

for small_list in big_list:
    pops.append(int(small_list[1]))

max_value = max(pops)
max_index = pops.index(max_value)

most_pop_country = big_list[max_index][0]
print(most_pop_country)
```

It basically finds the index of the largest population and then extracts the country name for it.

Comment: Does your answer have any advantages over Psidom's answer? It's pretty inefficient. Also, `max(pops)` compares strings, not integers, which is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, was writing and testing my answer when Psidon's answer was posted. The `max(arg)` does find the max integer value in a list though...

Comment: @tooty44 `max` doesn't convert strings to ints automatically.

Comment: @vaultah My bad. I didn't see that the asker had string population values.